# Decoding Hex: What does this line do (len & 0x01) != 0

Tags: java

I was going through a piece of code in the Apache commons library and was wondering what these conditions do exactly.

```
public static byte[] decodeHex(final char[] data) throws DecoderException {

        final int len = data.length;

        if ((len & 0x01) != 0) { // what does this condition do
            throw new DecoderException("Odd number of characters.");
        }

        final byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];

        // two characters form the hex value.
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
            int f = toDigit(data[j], j) << 4;
            j++;
            f = f | toDigit(data[j], j);
            j++;
            out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF); // what is happening here.
        }

        return out;
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [1337](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) (high performance) way of coding:

```
if (len % 2 == 1)
```

i.e. is `len` odd. It works because the binary representation of every odd integer has its least significant (ie last) bit set. Performaning a bitwise `AND` with `1` masks all other bits, leaving a result of either `1` if it's odd or `0` if even.

It's a carryover from C, where you can code simply:

```
if (len & 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

This checks if the last digit in the binary writing of `len` is a `1`.

```
  xxxxxxxy
& 00000001
```

gives `1` if `y` is `1`, `0` if `y` is `0`, ignoring the other digits.

If `y` is `1`, the length of the char array is odd, which shouldn't happen in this hex writing, hence the exception.

Another solution would have been

```
if (len%2 != 0) {
```

which would have been clearer in my opinion. I doubt the slight performance increase just before a loop really matters.

Comment: thank you that makes sense now. but what is happening in the second part ? (byte) (f & 0xFF). does it check if f is 255 bit long then ?

Comment: As there's a cast to byte just after, I really don't see why there's this `& 0xFF`.

Answer (score 1):

This line checks if len is an odd number or not.
If len isn't odd, len & 1 will be equal to 0. (1 and 0x01 are the same value, 0x01 is just the hexadecimal notation)